# IONIC 4 button event is not firing a function on clicking

Tags: ionic4

I have a simple button in ionic 4, i wan to run a function on clicking this button. but it seems like click event is not triggering.

**here is html**

```
<ion-content >
    <ion-button (onclick)="changeText()" expand="block" color="light"> 
      Click me
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button
    <p>My Name is {{text}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

**ts:**

```
export class HomePage {
    text = "Lakhan"
   changeText(){
   this.text="Ram";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-content >
    <ion-button (click)="changeText()" expand="block" color="light"> 
      Click me
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button
    <p>My Name is {{text}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks, It is fixed. today is my first day of learning ionic :)

Comment: it's ok :D nice to help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onclick you need to use click so

```
<ion-content >
  <ion-button (onclick)="changeText()" expand="block" color="light"> 
    Click me
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button
  <p>My Name is {{text}}</p>
</ion-content>
```

you need to change to

```
<ion-content >
  <ion-button (click)="changeText()" expand="block" color="light"> 
    Click me
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button
  <p>My Name is {{text}}</p>
</ion-content>
```